# How to convert photoshop CC shapes to paths to be opened in illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, svg, file-conversion

I'm trying to export some icons designed using shapes, effects, and masks to illustrator, but the problem is that the output is getting messed up. I believe this is happening because SVG only understands basic solids. If it was done in illustrator I would use "outline stroke" and get rid of all of the garbage. I have 500 icons and I don't have time to redesign them from scratch, so is there a method to convert the shapes inside photoshop to paths? so when I export from photoshop the SVG will not get messed up?

Comment: You can copy and paste paths between adobe applications, but that’s not necessarily ideal if you’ve got 500 to do.

Answer (score 2):

I've never done this with 500 paths, but it *should* theoretically work....

In Photoshop, choose `File > Export > Paths` to Illustrator.

That should create an Illustrator file. Open it in Illustrator. The path will be there, but they will be "hollow" (no fill no stroke) so you'll need to switch to **Outline Mode** to see them (View > Outline). You can then select them and apply fills/strokes as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can merge shapes, then export those shapes as paths to Illustrator, and use the pathfinder tools in Illustrator to unify everything - still labour intensive, but less painful than trying to do all that vector work in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "export as.." by right clicking all the layers you want to export.
[image]

Using svg seems to work just fine, all vector data is there when you open it using illustrator.

[image]

[image]